Random instance position in repeat zone
I have a group of 5 stars whose position is randomly generated.
I want to create a repeat zone that for each iteration generates a new group of 5 stars with a random position that overlaps with the previous ones. What nodes should I insert in the repeat zone to get the desired result? Thanks!


If you want to repeat the pattern, you don't need a repeat zone, just a new "instance on points":

If you want to multiply stars without copying the pattern, just add more stars:

If you really need a repeat zone for another reason, you need a different seed or ID for each random position (here I used a number taken from the repeat zone, and add 1 in each iteration)

If you need a repeat zone with different patterns, just put everything inside:

PS: The "geometry to instance" node is optional, but you might want that:

With the node: 4 instances, each instance containing 5 instances
Without the node: 20 instances


Thank you Daniel. I need the repeat zone method, and your last solution works well.  But I need a different star combination for every new instance, not the same pattern. Even if there are simpler solutions, I need to know if it is conceptually possible to solve this problem using repeat zones.

@Sergio, updated answer.

Thank you very much, Daniel. That's exactly what I was looking for.
